# Implement a minimum flush size for io.BufferedWriter in Python

Tags: python, io, stream, buffer

I'm extending the `BufferedWriter` class from the `io` module and so far it looks something like this:

```
class MyBufferedWriter(io.BufferedWriter):
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, config, buffer_size=5242880):
        if buffer_size < 5242880:
            raise Exception(f"Buffer size of {buffer_size} is too small. Must be at least 5242880")
        return cls(MyRawWriter.open(config), buffer_size=buffer_size)
```

`MyRawWriter` is a custom io class that writes data via an API. That API has a minimum size that it will accept in a given write. How can I implement a flush logic that requires the buffer to be a *minimum* size, in addition to the *maximum* size of `buffer_size`?

I was thinking I could override the `flush()` method, check the size of the buffer and call `super().flush()` if the buffer exceeded the minimum. But I can't find anything in the documentation on how to find the size of the internal buffer.

Comment: maybe you should create own `__init__` and keep it as `self.buffer_size`

Comment: it is probably `C/C++` source code for [BufferedWriter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c#L1907) and it keeps `buffer_size` in `C/C+` - and I don't see any method to get it in `Python`, so you may have to keep it in own variable.